# Unknown index match issue

Tags: vba, excel

I get the error for the code below

> Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

Can anyone see what the issue is here?

```
Dim to_do As Worksheet, ordered As Worksheet
Set to_do = Sheets("To do log")
Set ordered = Sheets("Working File")

to_do.Range(G4).Formula = _ 
   Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(ordered.Range("F:F"), _
   Application.Match(to_do.Range("B4"), ordered.Range("B:B"), 0))
```

Comment: `to_do.Range(G4)` isn't a valid definition. It should be `to_do.Range("G4") and I would suggest that you use the Value property unless it is a formula you wish to assign, but your code assigns a Value (default)

Comment: `to_do.Range("G4").Formula = `, dont forget the double-quotes. You could spot it immediately if you had set `Option Explicit`...

Comment: @Variatus I think you should add it as an answer

Comment: Thank you, @Shai Rado. A.S.H. didn't, either :-)

Comment: @Variatus LOL it's about who is first, it's about having an answer here when somone in the future searches for this topic and looking for an answer - he will se an answer here with **V** mark and some up-votes, then he'll know he got a reliable answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`to_do.Range(G4)` isn't a valid definition. It should be `to_do.Range("G4")`. @A.S.H. pointed out correctly that your VBA would highlight the error first time you run the code if you'll use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code sheet.

I suggest that you use the `Value` property to assign the value to, unless it is a `Formula` you wish to assign, but your code assigns a value because the `INDEX` function returns a range for which the `Value` property is the default. If you wanted the formula you would have to specify it.

Answer (score 1):

You quickly can solve your problem given the Worksheet names, so you don't need declare them in your code. 
You're intending to print a formula in a cell, so you also can use the FormulaR1C1. 
My solution for your problem is that:

[image]

```
wsTodo.Range("G4").FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX('" & wsWorkingFile.Name & "'!C6,MATCH(R4C2,'" & wsWorkingFile.Name & "'!C2))"
```

For the change the goes to VBAproject click in the worksheet and give it a name in the property (name).

[image]

What do you solved with this code:

- You don't need to worry about if the sheet changes names
- You can code quicker if you change the name of the plans
- You don't need to declare the sheet everytime